# Scala PriorityQueue on Array[Int] performance issue with complex comparison function (caching is needed)

Tags: performance, scala, caching, priority-queue, large-data

The problem involves the Scala PriorityQueue[Array[Int]] performance on large data set. The following operations are needed: enqueue, dequeue, and filter. Currently, my implementation is as follows:

For every element of type Array[Int], there is a complex evaluation function: (I'm not sure how to write it in a more efficient way, because it excludes the position 0)

```
def eval_fun(a : Array[Int]) =
  if(a.size < 2) 3
  else {
    var ret = 0
    var i = 1
    while(i < a.size) {
      if((a(i) & 0x3) == 1) ret += 1
      else if((a(i) & 0x3) == 3) ret += 3
      i += 1
    }
    ret / a.size
  }
```

The ordering with a comparison function is based on the evaluation function: (*Reversed*, descendent order)

```
val arr_ord = new Ordering[Array[Int]] {
  def compare(a : Array[Int], b : Array[Int]) = eval_fun(b) compare eval_fun(a) }
```

The PriorityQueue is defined as:

```
val pq: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Array[Int]] = PriorityQueue()
```

Question:

1. Is there a more elegant and efficient way to write such a evaluation function? I'm thinking of using fold, but fold cannot exclude the position 0.
2. Is there a data structure to generate a priorityqueue with **unique** elements? Applying filter operation after each enqueue operation is *not* efficient.
3. Is there a cache method to reduce the evaluation computation? Since when adding a new element to the queue, every element may need to be evaluated by eval_fun again, which is not necessary if evaluated value of every element can be cached. Also, I should mention that two distinct element may have the same evaluated value.
4. Is there a more efficient data structure *without* using generic type? Because if the size of elements reaches 10,000 and the size of size reaches 1,000, the performance is terribly slow.

Thanks you.

Comment: Unique is another issue. val a = Array(1,2); val b=Array(1,2,0); val c=Array(1,2); After adding to priority queue, it should be sth like PQ(Array(1,2), Array(1,2,0))

Answer (score 4):

(1) If you want maximum performance here, I would stick to the while loop, even if it is not terribly elegant. Otherwise, if you use a `view` on Array, you can easily drop the first element before going into the `fold`:

```
a.view.drop(1).foldLeft(0)( (sum, a) => sum + ((a & 0x03) match {
   case 0x01 => 1
   case 0x03 => 3
   case _    => 0
})) / a.size
```

(2) You can maintain two structures, the priority queue, and a set. Both combined give you a sorted-set... So you could use `collection.immutable.SortedSet`, but there is no mutable variant in the standard library. Do want equality based on the priority function, or the actual array contents? Because in the latter case, you won't get around comparing arrays element by element for each insertion, undoing the effect of caching the priority function value.

(3) Just put the calculated priority along with the array in the queue. I.e.

```
implicit val ord = Ordering.by[(Int, Array[Int]), Int](_._1)
val pq = new collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, Array[Int])]
pq += eval_fun(a) -> a
```

Comment: pq += eval_fun(a) -> a is not correct. For example, val a=Array(1,2,3,4); val b = Array(1,2,3,4); after pq += eval_fun(a) ->a ; and pq += eval_fun(b) ->b; there are two elements. Actually, we only need 1 element

Comment: in (1): (sum, a) should be (a, sum). Thank you anyway.

Comment: in (2): Since it involves enqueue and dequeue, how to do it efficiently? thanks

Comment: @Tianyi: Yes, there will be two elements. A priority queue allows you to add multiple elements with the same priority. It seems you really want a sorted set here, instead. Forget about the priority queue. Note that the sorting order is reverse. `head` will give you the element with the lowest priority, thus make sure to use `-eval_fun` for the sorting. Also, the fold function really takes `(sum, a)`, see the scala API docs.

Comment: Then it is *not* correct:

    val a = Array(1,2,3,4)a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    a.view.drop(1).foldLeft(0)( (sum, a) => sum + ((a & 0x03) match {
       case 0x01 => 1
       case 0x03 => 3
       case _    => 0
    })) / a.sizeres0: Int = 0

Also, I tried your idea in my code. It seems twice slower. I'm not sure the problem. SortedSet has some problems, for example: val a=Array(1); b=Array(1); In Set, they consider them different elements.

Comment: `a.drop(1).map(_ & 0x03)` --> `Array(2, 3, 0)`. Mapped to the pris: `Array(0, 3, 0)`. Summed `3`. Divided by `a.size` = `3/4 = 0`. You might want to divide by `(a.size - 1)`? Note that arrays use object (reference) equality. Hence `Array(1,2,3,4) equals Array(1,2,3,4)` --> `false`. This problem goes away when you use the priority as key to the set.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use a tail recursive loop (generally these are more "idiomatic":

```
def eval(a: Array[Int]): Int =
  if (a.size < 2) 3
  else {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(ret: Int = 0, i: Int = 1): Int =
      if (i >= a.size) ret / a.size
      else {
        val mod3 = (a(i) & 0x3)
        if (mod3 == 1) loop(ret + 1, i + 1)
        else if (mod3 == 3) loop(ret + 3, i + 1)
        else loop(ret, i + 1)
      }
    loop()
  }
```

Then you can use that to initialise a cached priority value:

```
case class PriorityArray(a: Array[Int]) {
  lazy val priority = if (a.size < 2) 3 else {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(ret: Int = 0, i: Int = 1): Int =
      if (i >= a.size) ret / a.size
      else {
        val mod3 = (a(i) & 0x3)
        if (mod3 == 2) loop(ret, i + 1)
        else loop(ret + mod3, i + 1)
      }
    loop()
  }
}
```

You may note also that I removed a redundant & op and have only the single conditional (for when it equals 2, rather than two checks for 1 && 3) – these should have some minimal effect.

There is not a huge difference from 0__'s proposal that just came though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two more questions. 1) Is lazy method better than foldLeft? 2) how to eliminate same array? For example: val a=Array(1,2,3); val b = Array(1,2,3).

Comment: well, array.tail will cause a new array of (size - 1) to be created (if you don't use view as noted by Sciss), so the recursive version avoids this. Otherwise there shouldn't be a huge difference in the approach, but match may cause the double evaluation problem of `PartialFunctions` (once for is`Defined`, again for `apply`. For the second one, you'd need to have a memoiser of some form, which is worth a question in its own right.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for the memoir?

Comment: Well, Google's Guava has an Interner that is pretty simple. For a pure scala version though, here's one I prepared earlier: https://bitbucket.org/jwesleysmith/atlassian-util-scala/src/fd4ab78faed5/src/main/scala/com/atlassian/util/scala/concurrent/WeakMemoizer.scala

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. However, I'm still not clear about how to use your class. Can you give me an example?

Comment: It just wraps an initialiser function f: A=>B such that while the specific A value is around it will hold the B value previously computed for it. Syntactically if you have f: A=>B then you can:

val cachedF = WeakMemoizer(f)

Answer (score 1):

My answers:

1. If evaluation is critical, keep it as it is. You might get better performance with recursion (not sure why, but it happens), but you'll *certainly* get worse performance with pretty much any other approach.
2. No, there isn't, but you can come pretty close to it just modifying the dequeue operation:

   def distinctDequeue[T](q: PriorityQueue[T]): T = {
     val result = q.dequeue
     while (q.head == result) q.dequeue
     result
   }

Otherwise, you'd have to keep a second data structure just to keep track of whether an element has been added or not. Either way, that equals sign is pretty heavy, but I have a suggestion to make it faster in the next item.

Note, however, that this requires that ties on the the cost function get solved in some other way.

1. Like 0__ suggested, put the cost on the priority queue. But you can *also* keep a cache on the function if that would be helpful. I'd try something like this:

   val evalMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMapWrappedArray[Int], Int
   def eval_fun(a : Array[Int]) =
     if(a.size < 2) 3
     else evalMap.getOrElseUpdate(a, {
         var ret = 0
         var i = 1
         while(i < a.size) {
           if((a(i) & 0x3) == 1) ret += 1
           else if((a(i) & 0x3) == 3) ret += 3
           i += 1
         }
         ret / a.size
       })

   import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
   val pq = new collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, WrappedArray[Int])]
   pq += eval_fun(a) -> (a : WrappedArray[Int])

Note that I did not create a special `Ordering` -- I'm using the standard `Ordering` so that the `WrappedArray` will break the ties. There's little cost to wrap the `Array`, and you get it back with `.array`, but, on the other hand, you'll get the following:

1. Ties will be broken by comparing the array themselves. If there aren't many ties in the cost, this should be good enough. If there are, add something else to the tuple to help break ties without comparing the arrays.
2. That means all equal elements will be kept together, which will enable you to dequeue all of them at the same time, giving the impression of having kept only one.
3. And that `equals` will actually work, because `WrappedArray` compare like Scala sequences do.

I don't understand what you mean by that fourth point.